# Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Premature end of JPEG file in /vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, magento-2.1.2, data-migration

Recently I have migrated the magento-1 (ver: 1.9.1.1) data to magento-2 (Ver: ver: 2.1.2) fress version using data migration tool. And it working perfectly in our local computer (localhost).

I found an issue after upload it to server [m2.hiddencamera.com.au](http://m2.hiddencamera.com.au) that some product images not showing instead it showing blank image (http://m2.hiddencamera.com.au/hidden-cameras?cat=84). And this problem is for not generating the image cache in `pub/media/catalog/product/cache/` folder.

But when I try to regenerate the image using `php bin/magento catalog:image:resize` it showing a warning;

```
Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Premature end of JPEG file in /vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php on line 65
```

However in the mean time before showing the Warning it generate some new images cache in the `/pub/media/catalog/product/cache` folder.

I have tried to show the new generated images after `setup:upgrade, indexer:reindex, cache:clean, cache:flush`
 But it not updating the missing image url for the new generated images cache.

Also I have contacted with the hosting support (siteground) but no luck.

**Additional Information**

- Upgraded M2 Ver: 2.1.2
- Migrated from: 1.9.1.1
- PHP Version: 7.0.21
- memory_limit: 768M
- max_execution_time: 120

**N.B: I have checked after migrated the Magento1 data to Magento ver: 2.1.7 that it causing the same issue when upload to server, but working properly in localhost.**

I don't know exactly where the problem is. Please help me to resolve the issue for regenerating the product images.

Regards,